# How to check if all values of a javascript object within an array is true within React + Typescript?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, loops, boolean

I currently have a unique multiple choice test where some of the questions have multiple choice that are all correct. I'm currently trying to write something to check if every answer is question within the choice. `choices` is prop of type Array which holds multiple choice questions. I want to be able to check that `isCorrect` is true for each object within `this.props.choices`. Currently the structure looks like this:

```
"choices": [
        {
          "text": "Text 1",
          "isCorrect": true,

        },

        {
          "text": "Text 2",
          "isCorrect": true,
        }
  ]
```

Comment: let me know if that solved your issue or if you need any more help!

Comment: oh it worked out great! Thank you!

Comment: Turtlefish can you please mark the answer as correct below to signal to others that this question has been answered. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you want to use `every` on array so like this:

`choices.every(choice => choice.isCorrect)`

this will return true if all values are `true`